# How to efficiently write to a large number of files

Tags: c++, io, gzip, zlib

I am trying to write a program to split a large collection of gene sequences into many files based on values inside a certain segment of each sequence. For example the sequences might look like

```
AGCATGAGAG...
GATCAGGTAA...
GATGCGATAG...
... 100 million more
```

The goal is then to split the reads into individual files based on the sequences from position 2 to 7 (6 bases). So we get something like

```
AAAAAA.txt.gz
AAAAAC.txt.gz
AAAAAG.txt.gz
...4000 more
```

Now naively I have implemented a C++ program that

- reads in each sequence
- opens the relevant file
- writes in the sequence
- closes the file

Something like

```
#include <zlib.h>

void main() {
    SeqFile seq_file("input.txt.gz");
    string read;

    while (read = seq_file.get_read) {
        string tag = read.substr(1, 6);
        output_path = tag + "txt.gx";

        gzFile output = gzopen(output_path.c_str(), "wa");
        gzprintf(output, "%s", read);
        gzclose(output);
    }
}
```

This is unbearably slow compared to just writing the whole contents into a single other file.

What is the bottleneck is this situation and how might I improve performance given that I can't keep all the files open simultaneously due to system limits?

Comment: "efficient" and "large number of files" don't exactly go together. Instead of files, why not use a relational database?

Comment: Because unfortunately the large number of files is expected downstream. The pipeline was not set up to be very scalable and unfortunately has yet to be updated.

Comment: If the sequence only contains A, G, T, and C, then instead of compressing with gzip, you could instead convert every four bases to one binary byte (two bits per base) and write that out instead.

Comment: It is not clear how you are finding these 4096 possible 6-nucleotide breakpoints, or that they all exist, or that there aren't many collisions where the same sequence occurs at your chosen breakpoints.

Comment: There must be collisions, there are 100m sequences and 4096 possible files. Each file contains all sequences for which bases 2 to 7 are that of the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Since opening a file is slow, you need to reduce the number of files you open.  One way to accomplish this is to make multiple passes over your input.  Open a subset of your output files, make a pass over the input and only write data to those files.  When you're done, close all those files, reset the input, open a new subset, and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

The bottleneck is opening and closing of the output file. If you can move this out of the loop somehow, e.g. by keeping multiple output files open simultaneously, you program should speed up significantly. In the best case scenario it is possible to keep all 4096 files open at the same time but if you hit some system barrier even keeping a smaller number of files open and doing multiple passes through the file should be faster that opening and closing files in the tight loop.

Comment: One also wants to ensure that one writes out data in large chunks (like a couple of MB at a time). Lots of small writes kills performance.

Comment: I think I want to avoid multiple passes through the large file, from what's been posted I think the strategy is to keep a running buffer, then outputting then opening a file to write out to when the buffer fills up. This should avoid opening too many files, writing small chunks or making multiple passes.

Answer (score 0):

The compressing might be slowing the writing down, writing to text files then compressing could be worth a try.

Opening the file is a bottleneck. Some of the data could be stored in a container and when it reaches a certain size write the largest set to the corresponding file.

Answer (score 0):

I can't actually answer the question - because to do that, I would need to have access to YOUR system (or a reasonably precise replica). The type of disk and how it is connected, how much and type of memory and model/number of CPU will matter.

However, there are a few different things to consider, and that may well help (or at least tell you that "you can't do better than this").

First find out what takes up the time: CPU or disk-I/O?

Use `top` or `system monitor` or some such to measure what CPU-usage your application uses.

Write a simple program that writes a single value (zero?) to a file, without zipping it, for a similar size to what you get in your files. Compare this to the time it takes to write your gzip-file. If the time is about the same, then you are I/O-bound, and it probably doesn't matter much what you do.

If you have lots of CPU-usage, you may want to split the writing work into multiple threads - you obviously can't really do that with the reading, as it has to be sequential (reading gzip in mutliple threads is not easy, if at all possible, so let's not try that). Using one thread per CPU-core, so if you have 4 cores, use 1 to read, and three to write. You may not get 4 times the performance, but you should get a good improvement.

Quite certainly, at some point, you will be bound by the speed of the disk. Then the only option is to buy a better disk (if you haven't already got that!)

Comment: It's certainly not IO bound, there's around 5gb of data but it takes a few hours to get through it all. I don't want to parallelise the whole thing because my experience debugging parallel programs has been very poor, and I don't want to manage all the race conditions with multiple gzip strings fighting over the same files. RAM is limited, the decompressed data is around 50gb, so it will not live in my 16GB of RAM. I'd say the others are right in trying to limit the amount of file opens and closes.

Comment: So I don't know how long each sequence is, it's hard to judge where the bottleneck is. But yes, if you are doing multiple passes which open&close the same file, you can do a lot better. I was under the impression that each iteraion would write to one file only, but re-reading your question I understand that the same file may be "hit" many times.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suspect it's closing the file that is the more expesnive than opening it, since it flushes the content to the file. But admittedly, opening files in a directory with lots of files can also be bad - if you have 4000 files in one directory, that's quite a lot. Many tools that are built to handle LOTS of files will split them into separate directories, which may also help.